# generate random and unique key of exactly 10 characters based on longer input string

Tags: java, hash, md5

I have a requirement to generate random and unique key of exactly 10 characters for every record, based on some particular fields.
It should give me same key if I supply same set of information next time.

In summary I am looking for a way to convert a longer string to a 10 characters string, consistently.

Something like md5 hash but should output just 10 characters.

Thanks.

Note: As one of comments ask what I have tried. Basically I haven't found any proper solution and done lot of research on it.
The only solution I can think of is to store md5 hash and 10 characters key into a db which I can look up for next time. A custom 10 characters key can be generated which won't have any relation to md5 hash as such other than that mapping db.

Comment: You have a requirement, not we. Please show us what you have tried so far and we can help you with that.

Comment: What's wrong with MD5? Why is the length unsuitable?

Comment: user requirement. md5 hash aren't readable.

Comment: What do you consider to be a "readable" string? What characters do you want the strings to have? For example, A-Z, a-z, 0-9? What about special characters? Any other characters?

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking to do is not possible. The question title says, "generate random and unique key of exactly 10 characters based on longer input string".

By the [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), you can't do that. Because there are more strings that are longer than 10 characters than there are strings that are exactly 10 characters long, any hashing function you come up with will generate duplicates. Multiple long strings will map to the same 10-character string.

You can't guarantee uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

Convert string to char array, chsr to int and multiply last and first char, second and second to last, until you have a 10 digit number.

Comment: It doesn't guarantee uniqueness. Aren't 1xxxxxxxxxxxxx8 and 2xxxxxxxxxxxxx4 going to give me same key?